# Numpy memory-map loading does not own data

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-memmap

Assume I create an array, save it, and load it:

```
foo = np.random.random((3, 3))
np.save("foo", foo)

# Load as array
non_mmap = np.load("foo.npy")
non_mmap.flags.owndata  # True

# Load as mmap
mmap = np.load("foo.npy", mmap_mode="w+")
mmap.flags.owndata  # False
```

Why does loading as a memory map lose the ownership of the data? I want to resize in place, but due to ownership, it is not possible.

Comment: `non_mmap` is an array in memory, a copy of values on the file.  `mmap` is a way of looking at the the data that's still on the file.  `resize` would require changing the header as well as the size of data block on the file.  WIthout getting into the details, I'm not surprised that the `owndata` is False.

Comment: @hpaulj then the only way to resize would be to create a new memory-mapped array?

Comment: What's the `shape` of `mmap`?

Comment: Look at the docs and code of `numpy.lib.format.open_memmap` for more details on how `load` can open (or even create) a npy file as `memmap`.